# SignalR Memory Leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, signalr

we have an ASP.NET WebApi with a SignalR Hub running on two servers with a Redis backplane. Typically our api consumes 3gb - 4gb of memory but sometimes it happens, that there is a hugh memory spike to up to 20gb. I dont know the reason yet, but I assume, that It can happen when there are connection issues to redis (it is very rare).

I analyzed the dump file and found the following hints:
[image]

[image]

To be honest,  I dont understand it. It seems that it has something to do with exception handling, but I dont understand why the byte arrays are that big.

I am looking for ideas how to solve and have the hope, that something had the same issue.

Comment: We are experiencing the same thing.  May I ask which profiler you were able to successfully run against your signalR server?  We haven't found one that even allows us to get any insight without it crashing as well.  

Or better yet, did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you happen to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm also experiencing memory leaks, and using Windbg on a memory dump, I suspect that a Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer.SqlMessageBus instance is holding on to lots of objects in the SystemRuntime.Caching namespace. Was wondering if anyone found the same?